# query results not appearign in ssrs report when using where clause

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I have a TSQL query that works when executed through SSMS but when using the same query in an SSRS dataset it does not produce any results.

I removed the where clause in the TSQL statement which then displayed the results in the ssrs report but i need the where cluase in the TSQL statement to produce the output.

I have changed the where clause data type using cast/convert/int/varchar/date without any success.

Does anybody have a solution?

Although i tried filtering in the SSRS report itself which also did not work, i don't want to use this technique and the results will be output in csv.

Any ideas, thoughts, solutions appreciated - Thanks in advance.

Update: The report has no parameters and is designed to drop a csv based on contents of the sql below when subscribed to run;

```
    select TenancyRef, FullName, Telephone1, Telephone2,convert(varchar    (2),weekucpayday) wkpayday, substring(convert(varchar,getdate(),103),1,2) daypayday  --,Currentdate, paydate,  

    from (

    SELECT   CAST(RTRIM(ZZ.propref) AS nvarchar) + CAST(RTRIM(ZZ.tensuffix) AS nvarchar) + CAST(RTRIM(ZZ.checkdigit) AS nvarchar) AS TenancyRef, RTRIM(ZZ.perstitle) + ' ' + RTRIM(ZZ.perfnames) 
                         + ' ' + RTRIM(ZZ.persname) AS FullName, 
                         ZZ.Mobile_Number AS Telephone1, 
                         ZZ.Home_Number AS Telephone2, 
                         ZZ.tenind AS Status, 
                         ZZ.ArrearsBalance, 
                         a.ucdaycode, 
                         ZZ.tenaltkey,
                         cast(cast(a.ucdaycode as varchar)  +'/' + cast(month(GETDATE()) as varchar) +'/' + cast(YEAR(GETDATE()) as varchar ) as date) as paydate,
datename(dw,convert(date,(cast(a.ucdaycode as varchar)  +'/' + cast(month(GETDATE()) as varchar) +'/' + cast(YEAR(GETDATE()) as varchar )),103)) payday,

    datepart(dd,(case when datepart(dw,cast(DATEADD(dd, a.ucdaycode, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), -1)) as date)) = 6 then
    cast(DATEADD(dd, a.ucdaycode, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), -2)) as date)
    when datepart(dw,cast(DATEADD(dd, a.ucdaycode, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), -1)) as date)) = 7 then
    cast(DATEADD(dd, a.ucdaycode, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), -3)) as date) 
    else cast(DATEADD(dd, a.ucdaycode, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), -1)) as date)
    end)) as weekucpayday, 

    cast(DATEADD(dd, a.ucdaycode, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), -1)) as date) AS ucpayday
, convert(nvarchar,GETDATE(),1) Currentdate
FROM            [ucdetail                         ] AS a INNER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Z.propref, Z.tensuffix, Z.checkdigit, Z.tenind, Z.tenaltkey, Z.ArrearsBalance, Z.paymthdcode, T3.perstitle, T3.perfnames, T3.persname, T1.contdetails AS Mobile_Number, 
                                                         T2.contdetails AS Home_Number
                               FROM            (SELECT        T.propref, T.tensuffix, T.tenaltkey, T.tenind, T.checkdigit, occupancy.relncode, occupancy.occend, occupancy.perref AS OccPerref, T.tenarrsbal AS ArrearsBalance, T.paymthdcode
                                                         FROM            tenancy AS T LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                                                   occupancy ON T.tenaltkey = occupancy.tenaltkey
                                                         WHERE        (occupancy.relncode = 'T1') AND (GETDATE() < occupancy.occend) OR
                                                                                   (occupancy.relncode = 'T1') AND (occupancy.occend IS NULL)) AS Z LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                             (SELECT        perref, contdetails
                                                               FROM            [contdetails                     ] AS C1
                                                               WHERE        (UPPER(commtype) = 'T') AND (UPPER(commdesccode) = 'MOB') AND (UPPER(activeind) = 'Y') AND (UPPER(preferred) = 'Y')) AS T1 ON Z.OccPerref = T1.perref LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                             (SELECT        perref, contdetails
                                                               FROM            [contdetails                     ] AS C2
                                                               WHERE        (UPPER(commtype) = 'T') AND (UPPER(commdesccode) = 'HOME') AND (UPPER(activeind) = 'Y') AND (UPPER(preferred) = 'Y')) AS T2 ON Z.OccPerref = T2.perref LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                             (SELECT        perstitle, perfnames, persname, perref
                                                               FROM            person) AS T3 ON Z.OccPerref = T3.perref) AS ZZ ON a.tenaltkey = ZZ.tenaltkey 
WHERE   ZZ.tenaltkey not in (select postref from tranmisc where tranmisc.acctcode = 'ATBEN') and  ZZ.paymthdcode != 'DD' and    (ZZ.Mobile_Number IS NOT NULL OR
                         ZZ.Home_Number IS NOT NULL) AND (a.status = 'Active') AND (ZZ.tenind = 'C') AND (a.ucdaycode <> 0) --AND (a.ucdaycode = DATEPART(dd, GETDATE())) 

) AS UC where convert(int,UC.weekucpayday) = convert(int,(DATEPART(dd,getdate())))
```

Comment: You'll need to show more info. For a start, what is the T-SQL statement? Are there parameters used that are set in the report, if so, let us know where and what datatypes etc then somebody may be able to help. Oh, and please edit your question rather than adding info via comments, it's easier for others to read the whole question that way.

Comment: Hi Alan, Thanks for feedback. I've included the t-sql and have amended the where clause to various datatypes. There are no parameters in the report.

Comment: As the WHERE clause does not contain any parameters then datatypes is not the issue. I suspect your datasource is pointing to a different location than your connection in SSMS. Try right-clicking the dataset then choose query, then edit as text then hit the execute button and see what you get back. If you get results then you may have filters set somewhere. If you get no results, check the datasource target and credentials.